# Cant open tar.md5 files to view the .img files

Tags: rom

Im trying to open my stock rom file that i downloaded from sam firmware and when I try open it with winrar it says: The archive is either in unknown format or damaged. so i tried taking the .md5 extension away and still no luck? Other people have managed to do this besides me?

Comment: where do i fine that recovery.img file? Link please

Answer (score 2):

**Generic Samsung Firmware MD5 Information:**

You can flash an MD5 file via `Odin` for Samsung Devices.

An MD5 file is just a .tar file with a checksum included. Odin can recognise both, and you an even just remove the .MD5 and have .tar on the end, rather than the usual .tar.md5 extension Samsung software has. A tar file is just a *NIX archive file to all intents and purposes.

Note: MD5 cannot be flashed by CWM or TWRP or any other custom recovery.

For example:

- Lets say I download a new Modem called MODEM_S6102DXLC2_REV01.tar.md5
- Open ODIN
- Place MODEM_S6102DXLC2_REV01.tar.md5 in the 'Phone' or 'CP' section (Depending on Odin Version)
- Flash Modem.

---

**Opening Tar Files:**

To open a .tar file you can use 7-Zip in Windows.

[Link to 7 Zip Page](http://www.7-zip.org/) note it mentions Tar explicitely on the page.

[Here is a list of free archive software for windows](http://freebies.about.com/od/computerfreebies/tp/free-file-extractor.htm) many of which can open tar files.

Comment: where do i fine that recovery.img file? Link please

Answer (score 0):

> What is a MD5 file?
>   Files that contain the .md5 file extension are checksum files that are used to ensure that the data within a file is complete and has not become corrupt. An MD5 file verifies the integrity of downloaded files, discs and disk images. MD5 files use an algorithm that is based on the number of bits that a file should contain. The MD5 file format is used by the IsoBuster CD/DVD copying software to verify the integrity of the copies it creates as well as other software applications. However, there are certain applications that MD5 files are not suitable for, such as SSL certificate programs or digital signature file creation softwares.

Source: [MD5 file extension](http://file.org/extension/md5)

In other words, you may have downloaded the checksum file for the application/file/etc that you are attempting to download. The reason WinRar can't open it, is because WinRar is searching for compressed archives, not a checksum file.

Comment: I don't think this applies in this case. Samsung firmwares (From Sammobile) are *.tar.md5 and can be flashed in ODIN for Samsung devices. Also the MD5 is just an adition (checksum) to the tar archive. The above answer is generic, but it isn't entirely correct for Samsung firmwares. Edit: Confirmed here myself, can reomove MD5 from file and open as a TAR. It's 1.41 Gb for the firware so it's definitely not JUST a checksum file for sure.

Comment: @RossC For the record, the OP was not clear. I was under the impression that the OP was attempting to open a .MD5 file in WinRar - your statement is correct, if the file is a '.rar.md5'.

Comment: Yeah I get you entirely, I just noticed 'Samsung Firmware' and I've had a lot of confusion around this myself!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's always nice to learn from other people's perspectives.

Comment: No bother :-) been wrestling with Samsung firmware a while now. Still confuses me to this day!!

Comment: where do i fine that recovery.img file? Link please

Answer (score 0):

it is actually kind easy all you have to do is mount the .tar.md5 AP file and **Bam!**

you should find it